After filling forms and merging to one file, it shows the correct input on VS Code but not on actual file
I do not understand why VS Code shows the right names but when I open the file it is just a duplicate from the first file.
This is the code:
import { PDFDocument } from "pdf-lib";
import { readFile, writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import fs from "fs";

const testingName = ["Jane", "Test", "Jake", "Hank"];

export async function testing() {
  for (let i = 0; i < testingName.length; i++) {
    await createArrivalPack(testingName[i]);
  }
}

async function createArrivalPack(data) {
  try {
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(await readFile("./test.pdf"));
    const textFields = pdfDoc
      .getForm()
      .getFields()
      .map((f) => f.getName());

    console.log(textFields);

    const form = pdfDoc.getForm();

    // name
    form.getTextField("name").setText(`${data}`);
    let savedPDF = await pdfDoc.save();

    const firstFileCheck = await firstFile();

    if (firstFileCheck === false) {
      await writeFile(`./print/print.pdf`, savedPDF);
    } else {
      await addingPage(savedPDF);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function addingPage(savedPDF) {
  const pdfBytes = fs.readFileSync(`./print/print.pdf`);
  const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
  mergedPdf;

  const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(savedPDF);

  const copiedPages = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdf, pdf.getPageIndices());
  copiedPages.forEach((page) => {
    mergedPdf.addPage(page);
  });

  const mergedPdfFile = await mergedPdf.save();
  await writeFile(`./print/print.pdf`, mergedPdfFile);
}

//check if first file is there
async function firstFile() {
  try {
    await fs.promises.access(`./print/print.pdf`);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}

This is how it looks on VS Code. As it shows it has the correct name for each page on VS Code only:

As soon as I open the file on different computers and browsers, it just the copy of the first name:

I've tried to print it from VS Code directly but I can't even do that. It doesn't even showing me anything after 'processing' stuff.
What have I done wrong here and why does VS Code show the correct file while the actual file is not the same?

Node - v20.17.0
npm - 10.8.2
"pdf-lib": "^1.17.1"
macOS

